# MacBook Windows shift on external monitors after Catalina upgrade

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook-pro, macos-catalina

I have 2 external monitors connected to my MacBook, one horizontal, one vertical if that's relevant. They worked perfectly before. Since upgrading to Catalina, whenever I unlock it after being away from it for a while, I have to re-arrange all the previously opening windows. They would sometimes gather to one of the monitors, or some windows shift to the right edge of their previous desktops, almost not visible.
I continuously googled to see if anyone else is having this problem but didn't see any. Anyone has experienced the same? and is there anything I can do to prevent this annoyed behavior from happening?